# Div with text overlay an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to overlay a div on top of an image.

Here's what I've got so far, I'm totally stuck and have been for a while.

http://wilwaldon.com/learning/slideshow.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: http://wilwaldon.com/learning/student.html Looks alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.image{
 position:relative;
 width:1001px;
 height:257px;
 }
.overlay{
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
width: 300px;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 600;
}
</style>
```

Changes from original:

1. Add dimensions of the image to the container, and set its position to relative
2. Set overlay position to absolute and position it by top/bottom and left/right properties

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. Now that I look at it I feel a bit ashamed haha.

Thanks again, you rule!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `position:absolute;` on the overlay.  You might also want to add `background:transparent` if you want the image to show through.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the image as the background of your Div.

background-image: url (blahblahblah);